# Calculate the time difference

Tags: scala, java-time

I am trying to calculate time difference between 2 ZonedTime dates in Scala. I am receiving dates in **"2021-03-19T15:39:42.834248-07:00"** format as a String. I need the difference in seconds between 2 dates in Scala. **How to convert the string to zoned time and calculate the difference?**

Comment: For such data prefer to use `OffsetDateTime` over `ZonedDateTime`. Your string contains a UTC offset, `-07:00`, no time zone, like `America/New_York`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `between()` method as offered on a `temporal.ChronoUnit`.

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.SECONDS

val start = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-03-19T15:39:42.834248-07:00")
val stop  = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-03-19T15:49:42.834248-08:00")
val secsBetween:Long = SECONDS.between(start, stop)  // 4200
```

An alternative is to use the `until()` method on the `ZonedDateTime` instance itself.

```
val secsBetween:Long = start.until(stop, SECONDS) //same result
```

Comment: Thanks jwvh That Worked!!

Comment: Better to use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) rather than `ZonedDateTime`. No time zone involved here.

Answer (score 2):

[Java syntax, not Scala.]

## tl;dr

```java
Duration
.between
(
    OffsetDateTime.parse( "2021-03-19T15:39:42.834248-07:00" ) ,
    OffsetDateTime.parse( "2021-03-19T15:49:42.834248-08:00" )
)
.toString()
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/FXcJuv).

> PT1H10M

…which in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format means 1 hour and 10 minutes.

## Details

The [Answer by jwvh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66879659/642706) is close, but I would change a couple things.

### `OffsetDateTime`, not `ZonedDateTime`

Your input strings have only a mere offset-from-UTC but no time zone. So parse those as `OffsetDateTime`.

- An **offset** is simply a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the baseline of UTC, the line drawn through [Royal Observatory, Greenwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Observatory%2C_Greenwich). An example of an offset is `-07:00` which means seven hours behind UTC.
- A **time zone** is much more. A time zone is history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. A [time zone has a name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format of `Continent/Region`. Given our example above, on some dates, several time zones may share the offset of `-07:00`, including `America/Dawson`, `America/Los_Angeles`, `America/Phoenix`, `America/Boise`, and more.

```java
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2021-03-19T15:39:42.834248-07:00" ) ;
```

### `Duration`

Represent a span-of-time using [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html), on the scale of hours-minutes-seconds-nanos.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( sooner , later ) ;
```

Generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format.

```
String output = d.toString() ;
```